# VS2010 shows implicit variable to be of type 'var' instead of the actual type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, implicit-typing

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something else.

I create a new Web Application project in VS2010. In the project, I create a new class (Class1), with the following contents:

```
public void Test()
{
    var s = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

When I hover my mouse over `s` in the Console.WriteLine(s) line, a popup appears showing  `(local variable) string s`. Great, just as I expect.

[image: Correctly showing s to be of type string]

Now, I add an `App_Code` folder to the project. Inside it, I again create a new class (Class2), with the exact same contents (except the class name). Now, when I hover `s`, it shows `(local variable) var s`.

[image: Incorrectly showing s to be of type var]

Why is it showing `var` in stead of `string`? Is this a bug? Can you reproduce this behavior?

It's even worse. If I move Class2.cs from the App_Code folder to the root of the project, VS2010 still doesn't show the type. Even after restarting VS2010 and reopening the project, VS2010 will show the correct type in Class1 but not in Class2. I've also tried deleting the `.suo` and `.csproj.user` files, but still no difference. Apparently VS2010 caches this information somewhere.

Comment: Are there any other differences in the files? Usings? something else? What happens if you copy-paste one or the other and simply rename the class?

Comment: Well, if there's no differences in the files, you have conflicting definitions; i.e. it doesn't compile. The fact that it shows you anything in *either* file is amazing.

Comment: This is why a prefer not to use implicit types. Bug or not, I find it's easier to read if the type is explicitly used.

Comment: this happen even after rebuilding the project?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why would that lead to conflicting definitions? Like I said, the first file is `Class1`, the second file is `Class2`.

Comment: @comecme: No one cares about the *file* name. The important thing is the *class* name. Does your project build?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The first file contains class `Class1`, the second file contains class `Class2`. That's what I said: I create a _class_.

Comment: @comecme: Oooh... so just to check, the project builds, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, the code builds. But I'm not actually doing anything with the classes. I've just tried to actually instantiate them and `Class2` could not be found.

Comment: @comecme: Hmmmm that's really weird then, idk, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App_Code directory is a special directory for Web Site projects.

In Web Application projects, code placed inside the App_Code directory is ignored by VS.

[I noticed this behavior](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/differences-between-web-site-project-and-web-application-project/) when migrating a Web Site to a Web Application project.

Comment: That's interesting. If I create a Web Site Project, the `Class2` in the `App_Code` folder works like I expect. Hovering over `s` shows it's a `string`. I don't think code inside `App_Code` is ignored in a Web Application project. My code ran just fine, it was just the IDE not showing the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening due to `App_Code` folder. Because `App_Code` folder  compiled at run time. As MSDN describe here.

> In a Web site project, you can store source code in the App_Code
>   folder, and it will be automatically compiled at run time. The
>   resulting assembly is accessible to any other code in the Web
>   application. The App_Code folder therefore works much like the Bin
>   folder, except that you can store source code in it instead of
>   compiled code. The App_Code folder and its special status in an
>   ASP.NET Web application makes it possible to create custom classes and
>   other source-code-only files and use them in your Web application
>   without having to compile them independently.

[Here is MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Yes, it probably has something to do with the `App_Code` folder, as the problem only occurs on a class file inside that folder. Based on devio's answer, I discovered that inside a Web Site project, the problem doesn't occur. So basically you _can_ use `App_Code` inside a Web Application project, but you _shouldn't_ do that.